# Downloading a web page with Android

Tags: java, android, networking

I'm downloading a web page then extracting some data out of it, using regex (don't yell at me, I know a proper parser would be better, but this is a very simple machine generated page). This works fine in the emulator, and on my phone when connected by wi-fi, but not on 3G - the string returned is not the same, and I don't get a match. I can imagine it has something to do with packet size or latency, but I can't figure it out.

My code:

```
public static String getPage(URL url) throws IOException {
    final URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    HttpGet httpRequest = null;

    try {
        httpRequest = new HttpGet(url.toURI());
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest);

    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity); 
    InputStream stream = bufHttpEntity.getContent();

    String ct = connection.getContentType();

    final BufferedReader reader;

    if (ct.indexOf("charset=") != -1) {
        ct = ct.substring(ct.indexOf("charset=") + 8);
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, ct));
    }else {
         reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
    }

    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }

    stream.close();
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Is it my poor connection causing this, or is there a bug in there? Either way, how do I solve it?

---

**Update:** 
The file downloaded over 3G is 201 bytes smaller than the one over wi-fi. While they are obviously both downloading the correct page, the 3G one is missing a whole bunch of whitespace, and also some HTML comments that are present in the original page which I find a little strange. Does Android fetch pages differently on 3G as to reduce file size?

Comment: Have you tried comparing what is downloaded over 3G to what is downloaded otherwise?  How do they differ?

Comment: After much hassle I managed to get the files off the device - see updated question.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, you're unnecessarily firing TWO requests here. One with `URL#openConnection()` and other with `HttpClient#execute()`. Get rid of the `URL#openConnection()` line and proceed with `HttpClient`. The `HttpResponse` class has a `getHeaders()` method. Use it to get the `Content-Type` header.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for spotting that, I'd tried so many different ways of getting the file I'd left in that redundancy.

Answer (score 1):

UserAgent (UA) shouldn't be changed if u access web page using 3g or wifi. 
As it is mentioned before, get rid of UrlConnection, cause obviously code is complete for using HTTPClient method, and you are able to set UA using:

```
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT, userAgent);
```

last one..it might be silly but maybe web page is dynamic?! is that possible?

Comment: This worked for my issue of not wanting to download the mobile version of a site
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();       client.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0");

Answer (score 0):

Here you go some hints, some of them silly hints, but just in case:

1. Review your mobile connection, try to open web browser, surf the web, and make sure it actually works
2. I don't know which is the web page your are trying to access but take into account that depending on your phone User Agent (UA), the rendered content might be different (web pages specially designed for mobile phones), or even no content rendered at all. Is it a web page on your own.
3. Try to access that same web page from Firefox, changing the UA (Use the User Agent Switcher for Firefox), and review the code returned.

That will be a good start point to figure out what's your problem

Ger

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check if your provider has a transparent proxy in place with 3G.